# Configure Non-reusable cells collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview

If I create collectionView cells with unique reuse identifies how can I configure them ? I tried setting the tag value and then using `let button = viewWithTag(1) as! UIButton` and then use the button but that gives an error.

So far I’ve got the collectionView to display whatever it has in the storyboard, but I’m not sure how do anything with the contents of each cell using code. Each cell is a different size with different items inside hence I didn’t use the same identifier for each.
(Swift)

Comment: Don't use tags. For each custom cell create a custom class with `IBOutlet`s and connect everything in Interface Builder.

Comment: Why bypass the reuse of cells? It's optimized. You maybe misunderstood some part of the concept.

Comment: I did this but when I register the cell in the collectionview class the cell no longer appears @vadian

Comment: If you design the cells in Interface Builder **do not** register them.

Answer (score 0):

need to cast as `UIButton` before can use the button properties or methods

```
let button = viewWithTag(1) as! UIButton
```

Or with optional

```
if let button = viewWithTag(1) as? UIButton {

}
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo in the question @hafiz